# WatiN 2.0 Beta:Screensaver still not working

Tags: c#, automated-tests, watin

I have written a demo code to test the screensaver feature of WatiN.

But when I write the following piece of code intentionally to fail and save the screenshot, it just stops executing after the Assert.True ie where the test fails

```
using System;
using WatiN.Core;
using Gallio.Framework;
using MbUnit.Framework;
using Gallio.Model;


namespace Screenshotwhentestfails
{
    [TestFixture]
    class Program
    {

        public IE ie = new IE();
        [STAThread]
        [Test]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DemoCaptureOnFailure();
            DisposeBrowser();
        }
        [Test]
        [TearDown]
        public static void DemoCaptureOnFailure()
        {
            IE ie = new IE();
            using (TestLog.BeginSection("Go to Google, enter MbUnit as a search term and click I'm Feeling Lucky"))
            {
                ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");

                ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("MbUnit");
                ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnI")).Click();
            }

            // Of course this is ridiculous, we'll be on the MbUnit homepage...
            Assert.IsTrue(ie.ContainsText("NUnit"), "Expected to find NUnit on the page.");
        }
        [TearDown]
        public static void DisposeBrowser()
        {
            IE ie = new IE();
            if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed)
            {
                ie.CaptureWebPageToFile("C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Favorites.png");
            }

        }
        }
    }
```

It is throwing exception at

```
                Assert.IsTrue(ie.ContainsText("NUnit"), "Expected to find NUnit on the page.");
```

this step which was intentional but the Saving of screenshot at the specified location is not acheived.

Thanks for any help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you where using NUnit???  Anyhow, here's what you need to do.

You're not quite setting up your test correctly.

In your application go to File->New->Project... and add an "MbUnit V3 Test Project" (the c# version).  In solution explorer add a reference to the WatiN dll.

First add a new class for your tests with the [TestFixture] attribute: -

```
[TestFixture]
public class ScreenshotTest
```

Add as many test methods as you like: -

```
[Test]
public void DoScreenshotTest()
```

If you have some initialize/finalize code you want to run for ALL tests in this class you can add methods: -

```
[SetUp]
public void DoTestSetup()

[TearDown]
public void DoTestTeardown()
```

If you build your solution and open up the Test View window (Test->Windows->Test View) you should see your new test methods.  You can then right click and "Run Selection" or "Debug Selection"

Here's the full version of the code, HTH!

```
[TestFixture]
public class ScreenshotTest
{
    private IE ie;

    [SetUp]
    public void DoTestSetup()
    {
        ie = new IE();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void DoTestTeardown()
    {
        if (ie != null)
        {
            if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed)
                ie.CaptureWebPageToFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Favorites.png");

            ie.Close();
            ie.Dispose();
            ie = null;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void DoScreenshotTest()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(ie);

        using (TestLog.BeginSection("Go to Google, enter MbUnit as a search term and click I'm Feeling Lucky"))
        {
            ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
            ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("MbUnit");
            ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnI")).Click();
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(ie.ContainsText("NUnit"), "Expected to find NUnit on the page.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, in your example do you know that your making three separate instances of IE?  One in the class, one in DemoCaptureOnFailure and one in DisposeBrowser.